# Spring Security

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-security

I am trying to use spring security in my application developing restful web services and not getting the way how to send request to j_spring_security_check directly so that i can provide same url as a web service to Authorization of username and password.

Currently i am using following request pattern:

URL: "http://localhost:8080/CabFMS/j_spring_security_check"
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: {'j_username':'user','j_password':'123'}

Response: is Bad credentials

I am not sure about Content-type and body parameters. Please provide suggestion. To send request i am using REST Client

Tarun Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noticed `j_spring_security_checks` expects [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29), therefore you need to encode it as such:

```
j_username=user&j_password=123
```

Comment: Its working fine thanks for revert..but how i will authenticate for further requested web services. Is there any session ID mechanism support form spring security. If yes how to get that

Answer (score 0):

Your request pattern should be :

/j_spring_security_check?j_username=user&j_password=123

with method "POST" type.

other then this you can change request action & parameters text "j_spring_security_check" and "j_username" ,"j_password" by configuring alternate text in attributes :

login-processing-url,
username-parameter,
password-parameter

of spring "form-login" tag in security configuration xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **AuthenticationSuccessHadler** for this, in the authenticationSuccess method, return base64 encoded authorization header with the pattern **username:password**

Then, on each request, set the header as **Basic yourtokenhere**